# Select first booking of each vehicle in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpql

I'm trying to select the first booking of each vehicle but I am having difficulties. The query that I currently have is

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findBookingByVehicle", query = "SELECT c.colour, c.seats, c.make, c.model, b.departureDate, b.returnDate, b.bookingDate, e.fname, e.lname FROM Vehicle c JOIN c.booking b JOIN b.employee e WHERE c = b.vehicle AND b.employee = e ORDER BY b.bookingDate, b.departureDate ")
```

but it selects all of the bookings of each vehicle.

My table structure is:

[image: Table Picture]

How do I go about selecting the first booking of each vehicle?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF.

Comment: It does but I realized that it is probably not relevant to the question. Removed it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the query I already had to select all of the bookings from a vehicle and then removed bookings of a later date in the EJB.